# Split GitHub repo at some point in history

Tags: git

My project started with a **prototype** and then I developed an actual **solution** on top of it. The work was sequential, i.e. every new development branch was rebase-merged into master upon completion of a feature (and then deleted) - so I have a nice linear history. Now I noticed that the prototype itself might be useful and I want to extract it from this repository and create a new one.

To better illustrate my point, here's how my history looks like now (let's say that `TAG` means the arbitrarily chosen point in history when the prototype started to become a solution):

```
current repo: (ROOT)-----(commits)-----(TAG)--------(commits)---(HEAD)
```

And this is how I would like it to look:

```
current repo: (ROOT)-----(commits)-----(TAG)--------(commits)---(HEAD)  
new repo:     (ROOT)-----(commits)-----(TAG == HEAD)
```

Side question: is it possible to make it split them entirely, making them look like so:

```
current repo: (TAG == ROOT)----(commits)-----(HEAD)  
new repo:     (ROOT)-----------(commits)-----(TAG == HEAD)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whichever you want.  For the "prototype" repo, I would start by creating a "mirror" clone

```
git clone --mirror url/to/old/repo/origin
```

To make the prototype version of the repo is pretty simple.  You must want to move `master` back to the `TAG` that marks the last prototype version.  You'll have to locate that commit.  Say its SHA value is `ABC123`; then

```
git reset --hard ABC123
```

If you have any other tags or branches from more recent history, you'll probably want to delete them.  But since you say it's a simple, linear history, there shouldn't be much to that.  Then you can clean this up if you want.  There are a few ways; I usually go with

```
rm -r .git/logs
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

And this is now your prototype repo.  That gets you to the first picture.

Now if you also want to remove the prototype history from the "solution" repo, 
again I'd start with a fresh clone.  If this will *replace* the original repo, a plain clone is fine; if you're using this to start a new repo, again I'd suggest a mirror clone.

From there, there are lots of ways to do it, but how about

```
git rebase -i --root
```

An editor pops up with a line per commit.  Leave the 1st one alone.  Change the first word on the 2nd commit through (and including) the 1st "solution" commit to `squash`, then save and exit the editor.

After a little work, a new editor will come up showing the combined commit messages from the squashed commits.  Make this look however you want, save and exit.

If this was a regular clone and you're replacing the original repo, you now force-push the master ref back to origin.  Note that this is an upstream rebase, and anyone else using the repo will have to recover from that.  (See the `git rebase` documentation.)

Comment: Thank you. I used the first part of your answer, but had to stop and think about squashing the original repo, as I have people forking it.

Comment: There is another option, called a "shallow clone", that might work in that case.  There are various options for setting this up (`depth=N` when cloning is maybe the simplest), but what it does is include only "more recent" history while still preserving commit ID's (which would help maintain historical consistency with forks)